# Merge two rust channel into one

Tags: asynchronous, rust, channel

I'm trying to merge two channel unbounded stream using [select_all](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.14/futures/stream/fn.select_all.html) into one.
It works with following code [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&code=use%20futures%3A%3A%7B%0A%20%20%20%20channel%3A%3Ampsc%3A%3A%7Bunbounded%2C%20UnboundedReceiver%2C%20UnboundedSender%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20stream%3A%3A%7Bselect_all%2C%20StreamExt%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20FutureExt%2C%20Stream%2C%0A%7D%3B%0Ause%20tokio%3A%3Atime%3A%3A%7Bsleep%2C%20Duration%7D%3B%0A%0A%23%5Bderive(Debug)%5D%0Aenum%20EventType%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20A(String)%2C%0A%20%20%20%20B(String)%2C%0A%7D%0A%0A%2F%2F%2F%20Generate%20event%20in%20a%20thread%0A%23%5Btokio%3A%3Amain%5D%0Aasync%20fn%20ev_gen(chan%3A%20UnboundedSender%3CString%3E)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20loop%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20chan.unbounded_send(%22Ev%22.to_string()).unwrap()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20sleep(Duration%3A%3Afrom_millis(100)).await%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0A%2F%2F%2F%20Merge%20event%20stream%20into%20one%0Afn%20merge_stream%3C%27a%3E(%0A%20%20%20%20sta%3A%20%26%27a%20mut%20UnboundedReceiver%3CString%3E%2C%0A%20%20%20%20stb%3A%20%26%27a%20mut%20UnboundedReceiver%3CString%3E%2C%0A)%20-%3E%20impl%20Stream%3CItem%20%3D%20String%3E%20%2B%20%27a%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20a_ev%20%3D%20sta%3B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20b_ev%20%3D%20stb%3B%0A%20%20%20%20select_all(vec!%5Ba_ev%2C%20b_ev%5D)%0A%7D%0A%0A%23%5Btokio%3A%3Amain%5D%0Aasync%20fn%20main()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20(a_in%2C%20mut%20a_out)%20%3D%20unbounded%3A%3A%3CString%3E()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20(b_in%2C%20mut%20b_out)%20%3D%20unbounded%3A%3A%3CString%3E()%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20std%3A%3Athread%3A%3Aspawn(move%20%7C%7C%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20ev_gen(a_in)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20std%3A%3Athread%3A%3Aspawn(move%20%7C%7C%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20ev_gen(b_in)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Display%20events%0A%20%20%20%20while%20let%20Some(ev)%20%3D%20merge_stream(%26mut%20a_out%2C%20%26mut%20b_out).next().await%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20println!(%22%7B%3A%3F%7D%22%2C%20ev)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A)

But I also want to map with an Enum from which one a value came from, so I map streams outputs

```
    let a_ev = async { sta.next().await.map(EventType::A) }.boxed();
    let b_ev = async { sta.next().await.map(EventType::B) }.boxed();
    select_all(vec![a_ev, b_ev])
```

but it fails to compile with a Stream not implemented error, [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&code=use%20futures%3A%3A%7B%0A%20%20%20%20channel%3A%3Ampsc%3A%3A%7Bunbounded%2C%20UnboundedReceiver%2C%20UnboundedSender%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20stream%3A%3A%7Bselect_all%2C%20StreamExt%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20FutureExt%2C%20Stream%2C%0A%7D%3B%0Ause%20tokio%3A%3Atime%3A%3A%7Bsleep%2C%20Duration%7D%3B%0A%0A%23%5Bderive(Debug)%5D%0Aenum%20EventType%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20A(String)%2C%0A%20%20%20%20B(String)%2C%0A%7D%0A%0A%2F%2F%2F%20Generate%20event%20in%20a%20thread%0A%23%5Btokio%3A%3Amain%5D%0Aasync%20fn%20ev_gen(chan%3A%20UnboundedSender%3CString%3E)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20loop%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20chan.unbounded_send(%22Ev%22.to_string()).unwrap()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20sleep(Duration%3A%3Afrom_millis(100)).await%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0A%2F%2F%2F%20Merge%20event%20stream%20into%20one%0Afn%20merge_stream%3C%27a%3E(%0A%20%20%20%20sta%3A%20%26%27a%20mut%20UnboundedReceiver%3CString%3E%2C%0A%20%20%20%20stb%3A%20%26%27a%20mut%20UnboundedReceiver%3CString%3E%2C%0A)%20-%3E%20impl%20Stream%3CItem%20%3D%20EventType%3E%20%2B%20%27a%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20a_ev%20%3D%20async%20%7B%20sta.next().await.map(EventType%3A%3AA)%20%7D.boxed()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20b_ev%20%3D%20async%20%7B%20sta.next().await.map(EventType%3A%3AB)%20%7D.boxed()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20select_all(vec!%5Ba_ev%2C%20b_ev%5D)%0A%7D%0A%0A%23%5Btokio%3A%3Amain%5D%0Aasync%20fn%20main()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20(a_in%2C%20mut%20a_out)%20%3D%20unbounded%3A%3A%3CString%3E()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20(b_in%2C%20mut%20b_out)%20%3D%20unbounded%3A%3A%3CString%3E()%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20std%3A%3Athread%3A%3Aspawn(move%20%7C%7C%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20ev_gen(a_in)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20std%3A%3Athread%3A%3Aspawn(move%20%7C%7C%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20ev_gen(b_in)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Display%20events%0A%20%20%20%20while%20let%20Some(ev)%20%3D%20merge_stream(%26mut%20a_out%2C%20%26mut%20b_out).next().await%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20println!(%22%7B%3A%3F%7D%22%2C%20ev)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A)

Comment: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a2aadd356c6ca7f8a334ecfc718dd2a8

Comment: I must said your code look strange